# MongoDb $lookup doing reads on foreign collection for each row

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

First time using the lookup operator on Mongodb and I found something strange. I have 2 simple collections that look more or less like this:

```
Book
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Title": "Some book name",
    "AuthorId": 1,
}   

Author
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Name": "Some Author",
    "Location": "US"
}
enter code here
```

There is also an index on Book.AuthorId.

So, what I wanted is to query all `Books` that have `Authors` in the US. So after reading the docs.. I came up with this query:

```
db.Book.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: "Author",
           localField: "AuthorId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "author"
       }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$author"
    },
    {
        $match:{ "author.Location": {$eq: "US"}}
    }
 ])
```

Which works great. But, just out of curiosity I turned on the profiling and looked what Mongo did when I executed the query above. For my surprise, I saw it did one Author lookup for each book it read. The whole point of using the `$lookup` operator was to not having to look all Authors before hand, so I'm kind of lost here. I'm not looking to group anything so.. having a `$group` before the lookup doesn't help me (at least I think so... enlighten me if I'm wrong)

Here you can see the profiling after I run the query:
[image]

Comment: which tool did you use to profile and see outputs? it looks like Robo 3T but i cannot find the profile option anywhere

Comment: @PirateApp first you need to setup the profiling level to 2: db.setProfilingLevel(2), then you can query it with: db.system.profile.find({}). To cleanup and start again, set it back to 0, and drop the profile with db.system.profile.drop()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've found a way to achieve this. Since there was no answer, I'm posting my solution.

So I had to "invert" the order of my query. Since I need to filter on Authors, I start with it and use the `$match` operator to filter it. That will reduce the records already. Then, I just `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` to show only book documents. So:

```
db.Author.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: "Book",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "AuthorId",
           as: "books"
       }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$books"
    },
    { 
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$books" } 
    }
])
```

And on the profiler, I only see one query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "Test.Book",
    "command" : {
        "aggregate" : "Author",
        "pipeline" : [ 
            {
                "$lookup" : {
                    "from" : "Book",
                    "localField" : "_id",
                    "foreignField" : "AuthorId",
                    "as" : "books"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "$unwind" : "$books"
            }, 
            {
                "$replaceRoot" : {
                    "newRoot" : "$books"
                }
            }
        ],
        "cursor" : {}
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 2,
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(26)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(13)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(12)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 4,
    "responseLength" : 312,
    "protocol" : "op_command",
    "millis" : 1,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-12-27T09:39:28.958Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [],
    "user" : ""
}
```